# Как сделать такой макет на flexbox?

Tags: css, flexbox

Нужно мне сверстать такой блок  я попробовал использовать CSS GRID получилось, но не знаю стоит уже использовать уже на реальных проектах решил и на flexbox сделать но не пойму как правильно раскидать на flexbox блоки?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подкиньте идею

```css
.grid {
    display: grid;
    padding-right: 0.9375rem;
    padding-left: 0.9375rem;
    max-width: 75rem;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.categories {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
    grid-gap: 10px;
}

.catblock {
    min-height: 32vh;
    padding: 10px;
}

.catblock:nth-child(1) {
    grid-column: 1/3;
    grid-row: 1/6;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.catblock:nth-child(2) {
    grid-row: 1/2;
    border: 1px solid green;
}

.catblock:nth-child(3) {
    border: 1px solid blue;
}

.catblock:nth-child(4) {
    grid-column: 3/5;
    border: 1px solid #222;
    grid-row: 2/6;
}

.catblock:nth-child(5) {
    grid-column: 1/3;
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
}

.catblock:nth-child(6) {
    border: 1px solid #666;
}

.catblock:nth-child(7) {
    border: 1px solid #777;
}

.categoryItem {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    max-width: 75rem;
    margin: auto;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -ms-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.category__items {
    border: 1px solid #111;
    min-height: 32vh;
    padding: 10px;
}

.category__items:nth-child(1) {
    width: 50%;
    height: 400px;
}

.category__items:nth-child(2) {
    width: 25%;
    height: 200px;
}

.category__items:nth-child(3) {
    width: 25%;
    height: 200px;
}

.category__items:nth-child(4) {
    width: 50%;
}

.category__items:nth-child(5) {
    width: 50%;
}

.category__items:nth-child(6) {
    width: 25%;
}

.category__items:nth-child(7) {
    width: 25%;
}
```

```html
<div class="categories grid">
    <div class="catblock"><a href="">Ведущие диджеи 1</a></div>
    <div class="catblock">Ведущие диджеи 2</div>
    <div class="catblock">Ведущие диджеи 3</div>
    <div class="catblock"><a href="">Ведущие диджеи 4</a></div>
    <div class="catblock"><a href="">Ведущие диджеи 5</a></div>
    <div class="catblock"><a href="">Ведущие диджеи 6</a></div>
    <div class="catblock"><a href="">Ведущие диджеи 7</a></div>
</div>
<hr>
<hr>
<div class="categoryItem">
    <div class="category__items"><a href="">Ведущие диджеи 1</a></div>
    <div class="category__items">Ведущие диджеи 2</div>
    <div class="category__items">Ведущие диджеи 3</div>
    <div class="category__items"><a href="">Ведущие диджеи 4</a></div>
    <div class="category__items"><a href="">Ведущие диджеи 5</a></div>
    <div class="category__items"><a href="">Ведущие диджеи 6</a></div>
    <div class="category__items"><a href="">Ведущие диджеи 7</a></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы правы, использовать гриды на бою всё ещё опасно. А на флексах это можно сделать например [вот так](https://jsfiddle.net/7rdn5pok/9/)

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="rowx2">

    </div>
    <div class="row"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="half"></div>
      <div class="half"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row"></div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="half"></div>
      <div class="half"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 600px;
  height: 450px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
}

.col {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.row {
  flex: 0 0 calc( 100% / 3 );
  border: 1px solid blue;
  display: flex;
}

.rowx2 {
  flex: 0 0 calc( 100% / 3 * 2 );
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.half {
  border: 1px solid green;
  flex: 0 0 50%;
}
```